# Applying for student visa from a country which I am not a citizen of and staying there on tourist visa

Tags: germany, student-visa, bangladeshi-citizens

I am a citizen of **country** **A** (Bangladesh). I want to study in **country** **B** (Germany). I am visiting **country C** on a 2 month tourist visa. Can I apply for a student visa in **country B** from **country C** (most likely going to be India/Norway/Finland) where I am a tourist and not a citizen?

Comment: This will depend on a) how Country B manages its consular (visa-issuing) processes, and/or b) whether Country B maintains a consulate in Country C. Without knowing what countries you're talking about, no answer is possible. If you reveal those country names, it's possible — but not certain — that someone will know the answer.

Comment: Typically applications for a non-visitor type visa such as a student visa must be done from the applicant’s country of residence. There may be exceptions to that but to get an answer you will need to edit your question to state the countries concerned. In addition, you should also consider the visa *processing* time - will you get a decision before your stay as a visitor expires.

Comment: I am a citizen of Bangladesh. I want to study in Germany. Country C is most likely going to be India/Norway/Finland

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the *German* text at the [relevant page](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/service/fragenkatalog-node/08-studentenvisum/606218) of the homepage of the German foreign office (emphasis mine)

> Ausländer müssen grundsätzlich vor der Einreise nach Deutschland bei der **zuständigen** deutschen Auslandsvertretung zunächst ein Studentenvisum beantragen.

> As a matter of principle, foreigners have to apply for a student visa at the **responsible** German mission abroad before travelling to Germany.

(the relevant English page is [here](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/visa-service/buergerservice/faq/08-studentenvisum/606690), but for some reason omits the "zuständig" bit)

There are a few reasons why such rules make sense. E.g. the foreign mission in Finland might not be familiar with the education system in Bangladesh and therefore be unable to conduct a quick sanity check of the application. Or in the case of Norway or Finland, they might not have the staff to process such requests because residents of these two countries generally do not need visas for Germany.

At the same time, there are several scenarios where the responsible mission abroad *might* be located in some country C:

- country B does not have a mission in country A. This may be for political reasons (e.g. US in Iran), security reasons (most countries in Afghanistan) or simply for financial reasons (e.g. Austria in Mongolia). In such cases the responsible foreign mission will often be in some neighbouring country, or sometimes you have to go to the foreign mission of some country D in country A, which handles affairs for country B.
- you are a long term resident of country C

I think neither of the two is relevant in your case. With that said, since that Foreign Office website is a bit ambigious and may not reflect actual practice anyway, I'd suggest you just contact the respective German foreign missions and ask them. It might be possible to apply anyway, but I would not count on it.

Comment: (+1) German rules and practices is what matters here so the answer is completely correct but it's interesting to note that the traditional justification has gotten weaker and some countries have reorganised their operations to make sure you can lodge your application wherever you want, forwarding all documents electronically to another consular post if needed (I think Canada works that way).